# sizeof character array for a dynamically created array

Tags: c++

I need to create a char array dynamically based on the pattern length, i.e., `plen`. However, when I do `sizeof(table)`, I get 8. Why am I getting `8` instead of `3`?

```cpp
int main() {
    char *pattern = "aaa";
    int plen = strlen(pattern);
    char *table = new char[plen + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < plen; i++) {
        table[i] = pattern[i];
    }
    cout << sizeof(table) << plen << table;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is `83aaa...`: `8` for `sizeof(table)`, `3` for `plen` and `aaa` for `table`, which has the stored value of pattern.

Comment: `sizeof` happens at compile time, based on the type.

Comment: well when i do strlen i get 3..since its a character array.but i dont know how it gets 8 when i do sizeof.

Comment: because table is a pointer and the size of a pointer is 8 byte on your system

Comment: If you are treating `table` like a string, make sure it is null terminated and then check length with `strlen`.

Comment: A pointer is not holding data, but pointing to an address where the data is.

Comment: @misthacoder, `strlen` is just a function, called at runtim like any other. `sizeof` is an operator that is evaluated before the program starts running, meaning it cannot possibly know how many characters are in a string by the pointer. Of course this entire code could be replaced with `std::string pattern = "aaa"; std::string table = pattern; std::cout << table.size() << pattern.size() << table;`

Comment: `sizeof` is both compile time and runtime no? For example, when used with C99's VLA's..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Yes, but this is a C++ question, and C99 is not C++.

Comment: One can also use `alloca` in C++ to achieve VLA's.. gcc/g++ also has VLA extensions as well..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames `alloca` returns a pointer. If you use `sizeof` on the result of `alloca`, you get the size of a pointer. (Also, `alloca` is neither standard C nor standard C++.)

Answer (score 2):

It is because `table` is a pointer, not an array. And the size of a pointer in your architecture is 8 bytes.

Comment: so if i use char *table=new char[plen+1]; or    int * t=new int[4]; and do a sizeof(t)or sizeof(table), i will get 8, since its a pointer.Well for a char *.. I will be doing strlen.I was just juggling around to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(expression)` is just a syntactic alternative to `sizeof(type of that expression)`.

In your example, `sizeof(table)` is just a syntactic alternative to `sizeof(char*)`. The value of the pointer or the char it points to or the array it points to are never considered for the result, only the type.